# Proguard issue:Android

Tags: android, proguard

After using prguard in android when we checked the code proguard is converting 'if'  to 'while'.  because of this my whole code logic is getting  changing.please  help if anyone knows the solution

Comment: This is just very difficult to believe, are you saying that constantly when you compile it transforms all your `if(condition){}` statements in your project into `while(condition)` ? Have you tried to clean the code?

Comment: Not in all  the files but in some of the files "IF"  to 'WHILE'  and if am giving 'ELSE  IF' to 'FOR'  :( . Even  I try to exclude code optimistaionm still its happening

Comment: haha....I just raised the same issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024421/abnormal-behavior-while-using-proguard